# Writing $28913000$ as the sum of two squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A little number theory fun. I am given that $167^2 + 32^2 = 28913$, and I am asked to find integers $a$ and $b$, such that $a^2 + b^2 = 28913000$.

Here's my thought process so far:

Knowing that $1000 = 10^2 + 30^2$, I rewrote $28913000$ as $28913\times 1000$, and proceeded to multiply the sums of squares:

$$(167^2 + 32^2)(10^2 + 30^2).$$

However, after foiling, I ended up with the sum of $4$ squares, and cannot think of a way to just find two squares, $a$ and $b$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: think of complex numbers, their multiplication, and their absolute-value-squared.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Very good!

Do you know *complex numbers*? Assume that $-1$ has a square root *somewhere* (certainly not in $\mathbb R$), denote it $i$, and introduce $+$, $\cdot$ operations with reals and $i$.
So, $i^2=-1$, thus $(a+bi)(a-bi) = a^2+b^2$.
$$(a+bi)(a-bi)(c+di)(c-di) = (a+bi)(c+di)\cdot (a-bi)(c-di)$$
Can you calculate it?

Comment: Excellent! By treating the sum of squares in the reals as complex conjugates, the equation you wrote above provides a way to travel between the product of two sums of squares (the right side) to the sum of two squares (left side). Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can easily check that
$$
(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ac-bd)^2+(ad+bc)^2
$$

Comment: See: [Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity)

Answer (score 0):

One can also find all of the solutions computationally.  E.g. here's some [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) code:

```
n:=28913000;;

for a in [0..RootInt(n)] do
  b:=n-a^2;
  c:=RootInt(b);
  if(IsSquareInt(b)) then
    Print(a^2+c^2," = ",a,"^2 + ",c,"^2\n");
  fi;
od;
```

which gives

```
28913000 = 182^2 + 5374^2
28913000 = 710^2 + 5330^2
28913000 = 1330^2 + 5210^2
28913000 = 2062^2 + 4966^2
28913000 = 2174^2 + 4918^2
28913000 = 2630^2 + 4690^2
28913000 = 3370^2 + 4190^2
28913000 = 3766^2 + 3838^2
28913000 = 3838^2 + 3766^2
28913000 = 4190^2 + 3370^2
28913000 = 4690^2 + 2630^2
28913000 = 4918^2 + 2174^2
28913000 = 4966^2 + 2062^2
28913000 = 5210^2 + 1330^2
28913000 = 5330^2 + 710^2
28913000 = 5374^2 + 182^2
```